# update multiple checkbox with javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

I am working with multiple checkboxes with javascript and ajax. When the checkbox is clicked the javascript send with ajax the values to trata.php (these values: checked if is true or false and the id of that checkbox)...but the id always show me undefined....can you guide me, please.

Here is the JS:

```
$("div.feature").click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = "Cara=" + checked + "&Id=" + Id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "trata.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#tr").show();
            $("#t").empty();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#tr").hide();
            $("#t").append(response);
        }
    })
    return false;
});

$("div.feature1").click(function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = "Pieza=" + checked + "&Id=" + Id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "trata.php?ts=" + new Date().getTime(),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#tr").show();
            $("#t").empty();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#tr").hide();
            $("#t").append(response);
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

In page this is the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="feature" align="center">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>" name="Id" id="Id" /> <!-- in this Id the value is 1 -->
                <input type="checkbox" data-no-uniform="true" class="iphone-toggle" <?php if ($row[ 'Cara']=='1' ) {echo 'name="Cara" value="on"  checked="checked"';} else { echo 'name="Cara" value="off"'; } ?>>
            </div>
            <div id="tr" style="display:none;" align="center"><img src="img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-1.gif" />
            </div>
            <div id="t"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="feature1" align="center">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" name="Id" id="Id" /> <!-- in this Id the value is 2 -->
                <input type="checkbox" data-no-uniform="true" class="iphone-toggle" <?php if ($row[ 'Pieza']=='1' ) {echo 'name="Pieza" value="on"  checked="checked"';} else { echo 'name="Pieza" value="off"'; } ?>>
            </div>
            <div id="tr" style="display:none;" align="center"><img src="img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-1.gif" />
            </div>
            <div id="t"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In trata.php //MySQL + PDO

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['Cara'])) {
    try{
        $Id = $_POST['Id'];
    if ($_POST['Cara'] == false) {
        global $Cara;
        $Cara = 0;
    } else if ($_POST['Cara'] == true) {
        global $Cara;
        $Cara = 1;
    };
        $sql = "UPDATE Trata SET 
        Cara = :Cara
        WHERE Id= :Id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Cara', $Cara, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div class='alert alert-block alert-primary fade in'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                ok.
            </div>";
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
} if(isset($_POST['Pieza'])) {
    try{
        $Id = $_POST['Id'];
    if ($_POST['Pieza'] == false) {
        global $Pieza;
        $Pieza = 0;
    } else if ($_POST['Pieza'] == true) {
        global $Pieza;
        $Pieza = 1;
    };
        $sql = "UPDATE Trata SET 
        Pieza = :Pieza
        WHERE Id= :Id";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Pieza', $Pieza, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Id', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div class='alert alert-block alert-primary fade in'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                ok.
            </div>";
    }catch(PDOException $exception){ 
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Another thing is the loading ajax is show me only in the first td and I have 8 td files..

Comment: This is a bit of a wall-of-code. It's too much to read though and not well formated. Could you please narrow it down to only the relevant pieces of code and the results you're seeing?

Comment: I was looking at the checkbox inputs and saw there are no ids ... also, in the locations where you do specify an id, they are all "Id"; ids should be distinct.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood the issue I have is the id of each id for the checkbox...the checkbox catch the checked(true or false) but the id is always undefined...I tried with `<form class="form-horizontal feature" method="post">` changing the div for form in JS but always show me the id undefined

Comment: sorry that is a mistake when I write this post..is `id` I already edited that

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood in effect yes I am a newbie

Comment: Sorry, I realised that could be taken offensively and I didn't intend that. But because you are new I'm willing to be a bit more opinionated in my answer to give you a simpler solution. I'm working on it now

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood don't preocupe, i am not offended at all. Thank you for your support

Comment: Ohh come on people...at least say why you put down vote...

Comment: They probably downvote because this question is too narrow and not a good fit for SO, and you've got way too much code up. You need to narrow it down and come up with a specific problem.

Comment: What are `Cara` and `Pieza`?

Comment: mmm...yes, probably is because that the downvotes...but when I write less or I don't inserted all the code some user's tell me "why I don't wrote the complete code for better understanding".... well is ok.

Comment: `Cara` or `Pieza` are the row in the Trata table in DB

Comment: It's a balance. You need some code for clarity but too much is just confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, this has turned into too much work. I can't answer it for you now. I'll try to come back but basically you need to be looking for the `checked` prop on the checkbox and currently you're looking at the `.feature` div.

Comment: Mmm in the log console I see the value of Cara (true or false) or the value for Pieza...but the id always is undefined...I understand my code is poor...is my first time with checkbox with JS and AJAX...always work with a form with submit button...I thought that will be more efficient...but I am very lost..heheh

Answer (score 0):

div.feature and div.feature1 do not have ids.  That is why $(this).attr('id') is returning undefined.  Try this:

```
$('div.feature input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var Id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: The JS not catch the click with this option

Comment: I quickly pasted together this jsfiddle and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/cleverKeith/3ssct8ke/